# Making clones of Google,Yahoo or Bing with Drupal,is it possible?

Tags: 7, theming, features

Is it possible to make a clone of any search engine in Drupal, and what can be the complexities in making it. Or what can be the nearest possible search engine to make with Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal isn't suitable for making a search engine. Try something like [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) instead

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could use drupal for the frontend of your search page, but you definitive needs some seperated search engine/index engine/crawler etc. to be able to get a good amount of data.